# How can i create Computed Column which gets data from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two table A and table B i want to created Computed column in Table A and get a value from Table B
Here is how my data looks like

Table A

```
Assembly Item        Component     
   123                400123         
   124                 400124
```

Table B

```
Item Id          Thickness           Notes      
400123           0.5           some text about 400123
400124           0.7           some text about 400124
```

I want to get something like this

Table A

```
Assembly Item        Component     Computed Col1      Computed Col1 
   123                400123          0.5         some text about 400123
   124                400124          0.7         some text about 400124
```

Comment: You can not create a computed column referencing from other table.[Computed Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx). You also can use triggers to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `JOIN's` not computed column.

You can create table valued function or view for this.

```
Create View taba_tabB 
As
Select A.[Assembly Item],A.Component ,B.Thickness ,B.Notes
From TableA A 
join TableB B on A.Component = B.[Item Id]
```

Comment: Yes but i want to populate the same when adding records automatically

Comment: @afri Yes it will populate the new records also. Read about view

Comment: How difficult is to display data from SQL Views in C# winform?

Comment: @afri - It is same as selecting a normal table. `Select * from taba_tabB` will give you the result of above view

Comment: Thank you, Can i perform insert too? this will save me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
     AssemblyItem VARCHAR(100),  
     Component VARCHAR(100),
     col1 FLOAT,
     col2 NVARCHAR(max)
)

CREATE TABLE TableB 
(
    ItemID VARCHAR(100),
    Thickness FLOAT,
    Notes NVARCHAR(max)
)

CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateRelatedColumn
ON  TableB
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE a SET a.col1=null,a.col2=null FROM TableA AS a INNER JOIN deleted AS d ON a.Component=d.ItemID

    UPDATE a 
    SET a.col1 = i.Thickness,
        a.col2 = i.Notes 
    FROM TableA AS a 
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON a.Component = i.ItemID
END
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TableA(AssemblyItem, Component)
VALUES('123', '400123'), ('124', '400124')

INSERT INTO dbo.TableB(ItemID, Thickness, Notes)
VALUES('400123', 0.5, 'some text about 400123'),
      ('400124', 0.7, 'some text about 400124')


SELECT * 
FROM dbo.TableA

UPDATE dbo.TableB 
SET Notes = Notes + 'aaa' 
WHERE ItemID = '400123'


AssemblyItem    Component   col1    col2
    123         400123      0.5     some text about 400123aaa
    124         400124      0.7     some text about 400124
```

Comment: This trigger is going to **crash and burn** in the case of a `DELETE` since there is **no** `Inserted` pseudo table available in that case ....